# Discord.js - is there an easy way to check if a player has a role or above

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I know of one way to check if a player has a role or above using an if statement and a whole bunch of elseifs. There has to be a faster and easier way of doing this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "has a role or above"?? What does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it right, you are trying to check if a server member has some role or any role higher than that given role (for example mod or higher). For that, the following could work assuming you have the member ID and the role ID:

```
async function yourFunction() {
  const guild = await client.guilds.fetch("your_guild_id"); //gets the guild
  const member = await guild.members.fetch("your_user_id"); //gets the member of the guild
  const role = guild.roles.cache.get("your_role_id"); //gets the specified role from the guild
  const role_position = role.position; //gets the position of the specified role (counted from the bottom of the roles list, the higher the role is placed on the roles list, the higher the role position)
  const highest_user_role_position = member.roles.highest.position; //gets the position of the highest role of the member
  if(highest_user_role_position >= role_position) { //comparison
    //the member has the specified role or any role above it
  } else {
    //the member does not have the specified role or any role above it
  };
};
```

How it works is basically it gets the position of the specified role (the higher the position is, the higher the role is placed - @everyone has position of 0, the highest role (let's say owner) will have the highest position) and the position of the highest role of the specified member. If the member has the specified role or any role above it (mod or admin, owner etc) - based on the roles list - the comparison will result in `true` and therefore it will run in the `if`. If the user's highest role is below the specified role (let's say "member" is below "mod"), the comparison will result in `false` and the `else` code will be ran.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple code:

```js
client.on('message', async msg => {
  await msg.guild.roles.fetch();
  let minRolePos = msg.guild.roles.cache.get('...').position;
  if (msg.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.position >= minRolePos)) {
    //execute code here for if the member has the role, or a role with a higher position
  }
}
```

The first line caches the roles
The second finds the position of the min positioned role
The third sees if the member has a role with a position higher than, or equal to that position

Comment: Your code has errors. You cannot use `await` without using `async`. Learn more about [await/async in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)